# Help with XPath query (count)

Tags: xpath, xquery

I want to count all descendant-or-self nodes of a certain node, but just all descendants which are lower than a certain level starting at 0. Do you have any suggestions?

Basically it seems something like:

```
count(//fstructure/node()) + count(//fstructure/node()/node()) + count(//fstructure/node()/node()/node()) + 1
```

works for 3 levels and the (element) node "fstructure", even if it's not really nice, but I just needed it for debugging.

best regards,
Johannes

Comment: Maybe this is one bad XPath-query, but I hope it's not right: count(//fstructure/node()) + count(//fstructure/node()/node()) + count(//fsctruture/node()/node()/node()) + 1     assuming I want to count 3 levels starting at the element node "fstructure".

Comment: ok it seems it's correct (despite my spelling mistake), but maybe not the nicest way to do it.

Comment: @Johannes: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, one-liner XPath expression solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XPath expression**:

```
   count(
    ExprForYourNode//*
                    [not(count(ancestor::* )
                        >
                         count(ExprForYourNode/ancestor::*) + 2
                         )
                    ]
         )
```

select all descendent-or-self *elements* off the element selected by the expression `ExprForYourNode` with maximum depth of 2 (zero based)

**If you want to select all  descendent-or self *nodes* (elements, text-nodes, comment-nodes and processing-instruction-nodes) use**:

```
   count(
    ExprForYourNode//node()
                     [not(count(ancestor::* )
                         >
                          count(ExprForYourNode/ancestor::*) + 2
                          )
                     ]
         )
```

**For example with this document**:

```
<t>
 <a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d/>
    </c>
  </b>
 </a>
</t>
```

**this expression**:

```
   count(
    /*/a//*
           [not(count(ancestor::* )
                >
                count(/*/a/ancestor::*) + 2
                )
           ]
          )
```

**produces**:

```
2
```

This is the number of elements (`b` and `c`, but not `d`) that are descendents of `a` with relative depth to `a` 2 or less.

**Similarly, the evaluation of this expression**:

```
   count(
    /*/a//node()
           [not(count(ancestor::* )
                >
                count(/*/a/ancestor::*) + 2
                )
           ]
         )
```

**produces**:

```
6
```

That is the number of elements (as before) plus the number of (white-space-only) text nodes at depth up to 2 relative the element `a`

Comment: Great, haven't even thought about counting the ancestors ;-)